# Google Workflows - Unexpected KeyError exception

Tags: google-workflows

We are experiencing occasional **KeyError** exceptions when processing a large volume of images using Google Workflows.
Our workflow is designed to process images stored in Google Cloud Storage. It is triggered by Eventarc events and utilizes Google Cloud Run services for image processing tasks.
Under normal conditions, the workflow operates smoothly, handling the processing load effectively. However, when the number of images to be processed simultaneously increases significantly, we occasionally encounter the following error:

`KeyError: key not found: code`

Despite this error, the Cloud Run services involved in the workflow do not report any issues. Additionally, the images, despite the error message, are processed successfully. This lack of correlating errors from Cloud Run services and successful image processing makes it challenging to pinpoint the root cause of the KeyError exception.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

We also checked that the resources were not exhausted and we were unable to determine the root cause of the issue.

**EDITED**, to add the code of the flow

```
{
  "main": {
    "params": ["event"],
    "steps": [
      {
        "step_init": {
          "assign": [
            {
              "flowResults": {}
            },
            {
              "errors": []
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_checkEventPayload"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_checkEventPayload": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${(event.data.protoPayload.resourceName != null) and (event.data.resource.labels.bucket_name != null)}",
              "assign": [
                {
                  "resourceName": "${event.data.protoPayload.resourceName}"
                },
                {
                  "bucketName": "${event.data.resource.labels.bucket_name}"
                }
              ],
              "next": "step_filterProcessedImage"
            }
          ],
          "next": "end"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_filterProcessedImage": {
          "try": {
            "call": "http.post",
            "args": {
              "url": "A",
              "body": {
                "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
              },
              "auth": {
                "type": "OIDC"
              }
            },
            "result": "filterProcessedImageResponse"
          },
          "retry": {
            "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
            "max_retries": 5,
            "backoff": {
              "initial_delay": 2,
              "max_delay": 60,
              "multiplier": 2
            }
          },
          "except": {
            "as": "filterProcessedImageException",
            "steps": [
              {
                "step_returnOnfilterProcessedImageException": {
                  "switch": [
                    {
                      "condition": "${(filterProcessedImageException.code != null) and (filterProcessedImageException.code == 409)}",
                      "return": "${\"Image \" + resourceName + \" already processed\"}"
                    }
                  ],
                  "next": "step_assignFilterProcessedImageException"
                }
              },
              {
                "step_assignFilterProcessedImageException": {
                  "assign": [
                    {
                      "filterProcessedImageResponse": "${filterProcessedImageException}"
                    },
                    {
                      "error": {
                        "service": "filter-processed-image-service",
                        "exception": "${filterProcessedImageException}"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "next": "step_assignFilterProcessedImageResult"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_assignFilterProcessedImageResult": {
          "assign": [
            {
              "flowResults[\"filterProcessedImageResponse\"]": "${filterProcessedImageResponse}"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_checkResultsBeforeCreateCopyImages"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_checkResultsBeforeCreateCopyImages": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${len(errors) != 0}",
              "next": "step_logErrors"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_createCopyImages"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_createCopyImages": {
          "parallel": {
            "shared": ["flowResults", "errors"],
            "branches": [
              {
                "branch_createIntranetCopyImage": {
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "step_createIntranetCopyImage": {
                        "try": {
                          "call": "http.post",
                          "args": {
                            "url": "B",
                            "body": {
                              "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                              "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
                            },
                            "auth": {
                              "type": "OIDC"
                            }
                          },
                          "result": "createIntranetCopyImageResponse"
                        },
                        "retry": {
                          "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
                          "max_retries": 5,
                          "backoff": {
                            "initial_delay": 2,
                            "max_delay": 60,
                            "multiplier": 2
                          }
                        },
                        "except": {
                          "as": "createIntranetCopyImageException",
                          "steps": [
                            {
                              "step_assignCreateIntranetCopyImageException": {
                                "assign": [
                                  {
                                    "createIntranetCopyImageResponse": "${createIntranetCopyImageException}"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "error": {
                                      "service": "create-intranet-copy-image-service",
                                      "exception": "${createIntranetCopyImageException}"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "next": "step_assignCreateIntranetCopyImageResult"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "step_assignCreateIntranetCopyImageResult": {
                        "assign": [
                          {
                            "flowResults[\"createIntranetCopyImageResponse\"]": "${createIntranetCopyImageResponse}"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "branch_createWebCopyImage": {
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "step_createWebCopyImage": {
                        "try": {
                          "call": "http.post",
                          "args": {
                            "url": "C",
                            "body": {
                              "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                              "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
                            },
                            "auth": {
                              "type": "OIDC"
                            }
                          },
                          "result": "createWebCopyImageResponse"
                        },
                        "retry": {
                          "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
                          "max_retries": 5,
                          "backoff": {
                            "initial_delay": 2,
                            "max_delay": 60,
                            "multiplier": 2
                          }
                        },
                        "except": {
                          "as": "createWebCopyImageException",
                          "steps": [
                            {
                              "step_assignCreateWebCopyImageException": {
                                "assign": [
                                  {
                                    "createWebCopyImageResponse": "${createWebCopyImageException}"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "error": {
                                      "service": "create-web-copy-image-service",
                                      "exception": "${createWebCopyImageException}"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "next": "step_assignCreateWebCopyImageResult"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "step_assignCreateWebCopyImageResult": {
                        "assign": [
                          {
                            "flowResults[\"createWebCopyImageResponse\"]": "${createWebCopyImageResponse}"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "next": "step_checkResultsAfterCreateCopyImages"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_checkResultsAfterCreateCopyImages": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${len(errors) != 0}",
              "next": "step_logErrors"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_detectText"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_detectText": {
          "parallel": {
            "shared": ["flowResults", "errors"],
            "branches": [
              {
                "branch_createSinglePageTxt": {
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "step_createSinglePageTxt": {
                        "try": {
                          "call": "http.post",
                          "args": {
                            "url": "D",
                            "body": {
                              "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                              "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
                            },
                            "auth": {
                              "type": "OIDC"
                            }
                          },
                          "result": "createSinglePageTxtResponse"
                        },
                        "retry": {
                          "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
                          "max_retries": 5,
                          "backoff": {
                            "initial_delay": 2,
                            "max_delay": 60,
                            "multiplier": 2
                          }
                        },
                        "except": {
                          "as": "createSinglePageTxtException",
                          "steps": [
                            {
                              "step_assignCreateSinglePageTxtException": {
                                "assign": [
                                  {
                                    "createSinglePageTxtResponse": "${createSinglePageTxtException}"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "error": {
                                      "service": "create-single-page-txt-service",
                                      "exception": "${createSinglePageTxtException}"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "next": "step_assignCreateSinglePageTxtResult"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "step_assignCreateSinglePageTxtResult": {
                        "assign": [
                          {
                            "flowResults[\"createSinglePageTxtResponse\"]": "${createSinglePageTxtResponse}"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "branch_createSinglePageSearchablePdf": {
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "step_createSinglePageSearchablePdf": {
                        "try": {
                          "call": "http.post",
                          "args": {
                            "url": "F",
                            "body": {
                              "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                              "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
                            },
                            "auth": {
                              "type": "OIDC"
                            }
                          },
                          "result": "createSinglePageSearchablePdfResponse"
                        },
                        "retry": {
                          "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
                          "max_retries": 5,
                          "backoff": {
                            "initial_delay": 2,
                            "max_delay": 128,
                            "multiplier": 4
                          }
                        },
                        "except": {
                          "as": "createSinglePageSearchablePdfException",
                          "steps": [
                            {
                              "step_assignCreateSinglePageSearchablePdfException": {
                                "assign": [
                                  {
                                    "createSinglePageSearchablePdfResponse": "${createSinglePageSearchablePdfException}"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "error": {
                                      "service": "create-single-page-searchable-pdf-service",
                                      "exception": "${createSinglePageSearchablePdfException}"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "next": "step_assignCreateSinglePageSearchablePdfResult"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "step_assignCreateSinglePageSearchablePdfResult": {
                        "assign": [
                          {
                            "flowResults[\"createSinglePageSearchablePdfResponse\"]": "${createSinglePageSearchablePdfResponse}"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "next": "step_checkResultsBeforeUpdateProcessingMetadata"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_checkResultsBeforeUpdateProcessingMetadata": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${len(errors) != 0}",
              "next": "step_logErrors"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_updateProcessingMetadata"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_updateProcessingMetadata": {
          "try": {
            "call": "http.post",
            "args": {
              "url": "G",
              "body": {
                "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                "bucketName": "${bucketName}"
              },
              "auth": {
                "type": "OIDC"
              }
            },
            "result": "updateProcessingMetadataResponse"
          },
          "retry": {
            "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
            "max_retries": 5,
            "backoff": {
              "initial_delay": 2,
              "max_delay": 60,
              "multiplier": 2
            }
          },
          "except": {
            "as": "updateProcessingMetadataException",
            "steps": [
              {
                "step_assignUpdateProcessingMetadataException": {
                  "assign": [
                    {
                      "updateProcessingMetadataResponse": "${updateProcessingMetadataException}"
                    },
                    {
                      "error": {
                        "service": "update-processing-metadata-service",
                        "exception": "${updateProcessingMetadataException}"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "errors": "${list.concat(errors, error)}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "next": "step_assignUpdateProcessingMetadataResult"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_assignUpdateProcessingMetadataResult": {
          "assign": [
            {
              "flowResults[\"updateProcessingMetadataResponse\"]": "${updateProcessingMetadataResponse}"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_checkResultsAfterUpdateProcessingMetadata"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_checkResultsAfterUpdateProcessingMetadata": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${len(errors) != 0}",
              "next": "step_logErrors"
            }
          ],
          "next": "step_returnFlowResults"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_logErrors": {
          "try": {
            "call": "http.post",
            "args": {
              "url": "H",
              "body": {
                "resourceName": "${resourceName}",
                "bucketName": "${bucketName}",
                "errors": "${errors}"
              },
              "auth": {
                "type": "OIDC"
              }
            },
            "result": "logErrorsResponse"
          },
          "retry": {
            "predicate": "${retryPredicate}",
            "max_retries": 5,
            "backoff": {
              "initial_delay": 2,
              "max_delay": 60,
              "multiplier": 2
            }
          },
          "except": {
            "as": "logErrorsException",
            "steps": [
              {
                "step_assignLogErrorsException": {
                  "assign": [
                    {
                      "logErrorsResponse": "${logErrorsException}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "next": "step_returnFlowResults"
        }
      },
      {
        "step_returnFlowResults": {
          "return": "${flowResults}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "retryPredicate": {
    "params": ["error"],
    "steps": [
      {
        "step_repeatWhen": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "condition": "${(error.code != null) and (error.code == 500)}",
              "return": true
            },
            {
              "condition": "${(error.code != null) and (error.code == 503)}",
              "return": true
            },
            {
              "condition": "${(error.code != null) and (error.code == 429)}",
              "return": true
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "step_otherwise": {
          "return": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the error in the logs or as a failed execution? Do you have a retry policy in your workflow?

Comment: Hi, each step has a custom retry policy (a subworkflow defines a custom, shared predicate) and custom backoff parameters.
Exceptions are handled and we collect and log errors; we see the error in the logs.
Observation suggests that each step can intermittently raise error "KeyError: key not found: code", particularly when processing large volumes of images, such as when transferring hundreds of images using the command "gsutil -m cp -r [...]".

Comment: We had a similar issue where we got a "connection broken" error in the workflow. The solution with google cloud support was the retry policy. The problem might still be there but the retry policy handles it. Guess your problem is similar. If everything gets processed and the error is not that frequent, I'd not investigate any further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that in the event of an error during the processing of an object, the flow won't add successful processing metadata to the object in cloud storage (we use custom metadata to filter objects in some downstream processing/queries).

Comment: Ah, but you wrote, that the images were getting processed successfully. Are you writing the metadata in the workflow?

Comment: I apologize for the previous inaccuracies in my description of the process. The workflow involves transforming TIFF-format images into multiple formats, extracting text from the original images, and generating searchable PDFs. Upon successful completion of all these steps, processing metadata is written back to the original TIFF object. However, when handling a large volume of images, certain steps may encounter errors, even if the corresponding services have functioned correctly. In such instances, the final step, responsible for writing processing metadata, is skipped.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just trying to understand your problem as I was lost as well on some problems with worklfows. Can you share your workflow code? We saw that there is a delay if you're writing a file or a row in big query to access it in the next step (because cloud replicas). So adding a sleep was the solution.

Comment: Hello, I edited the question and added the workflow code.

Comment: You use the key "code" (as it it saying in the error you're getting) several times. I guess in some conditions this key might not exist. To track that down, you could add logging steps right bevor steps where you use a the key "code". That should help identify the step which fails. https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/log-workflow

Comment: Hello, I introduced a logging step into the custom retry policy's workflow, which relies on HTTP code evaluation, and discovered that the underlying issue stems from a ConnectionError with the message "connection broken".
In the event of a ConnectionError, the code (HTTP) is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out the problem was a "connection broken" error and therefor your  custom retry policy failed, let me share my custom retry policy:

```
custom_retry:
  params: [e]
  steps:
    - retry_always:
        return: true
```

It looks stupid but it works :) As in the retry I define max_retries it's ok if it gets retried every time it fails (till max_retries reached). I haven't found a more elegant solution than this.

Comment: Your workaround is effective in bypassing the connection error. Do you have any insight into the underlying cause of the connection error?

Comment: We checked the connection error with google cloud support some time ago. My understanding of complex networks is that this can happen from time to time... Their answer was, that they are working on it. The error rate is way beyond 0.1%. I guess we have to deal with it.

Comment: I observed that when a ConnectionError arises, the error tags do not include the HttpError value. I think that a more structured custom retry policy could be written by adding a check on that condition: `..."switch": [{"condition": "${not(\"HttpError\" in error.tags)}","return": true},...`